# mySQL union doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following SQL statementL:

```
select DATE(bla), count(*) from tableA group by DATE(bla)
UNION ALL
select DATE(bla), count(*) from tableB group by DATE(bla)
order by "DATE(bla)"
```

What I get from the first part of the query:

```
(2012-05-07,  13)
```

And from the second part:

```
(2012-05-07,  15)
```

What I would expect to see after executing the whole query:

```
[(2012-05-07,  13),
(2012-05-07,  15)]
```

What I really get:

```
[(2012-05-07,  13)]
```

The question is why and what should I change to get what I expect?

Comment: There is no problem of your query, check your data again.

Comment: The brackets around the selects aren't necessary.

Comment: You have a comma in your desired output, do you want the 2 sets on 2 rows (as they would be with union) or in 2 columns on 1 row?

Comment: This must be something about your data (or a bug). You are asking us to *assume*, and I did more: I *modelled* your ‘expected output’ situation and used a very similar script: [it worked for me perfectly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c48a1/1). I then went further and changed the schema slightly to model your ‘actual result’ situation, and, surely enough, the [result was indeed identical to what *you* really got](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f266/1). So, please double check your data.

Comment: @AndriyM - I'm sorry, there was a mistake in my question, take a look at it now.

Comment: I have nothing to add I'm afraid. I worked on my examples to make them even closer to your situation, to illustrate that grouping by `DATE(…)` works just as well as grouping by a `date` type column. These are examples with UNION: [#1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19792/1), [#2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa75a/1). These are with UNION ALL: [#1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19792/2), [#2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa75a/2). (With UNION ALL you should *always* get two rows from your query.) If this is not about data, then you might have forgotten to post some vital part of your query (`LIMIT 1`, perhaps?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. You were right, the problem has something to do with the data. In the real case I had many rows but thought 'order by DATE(bla)' part of the query will sort them by date. This is not true, and this will be ignored until I add alias for the date field. And that's why I was so confused. Sorry for that, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` removes duplicate rows, try `UNION ALL`:

```
select DATE(bla), count(*) from tableA group by DATE(bla)
UNION ALL
select DATE(bla), count(*) from tableB group by DATE(bla)
```

Comment: In his example mnowotka took care to give non duplicated rows, so I guess he checked this issue. Else I'm gonna smash his virtual head :p

Comment: It doesn't matter - I changed my query to add "ALL" and I get the same results. I also modified my question no reflect that.

Comment: @OlivierCoilland I was assuming he add a bad example :P